# Primitive of $\sin(4x)$

Tags: calculus

If $\sin(4x)=2\sin(2x)\cos(2x)$ then:

$$\int \sin(4x)=\int 2\sin(2x)\cos(2x)$$
$$\frac{-\cos(4x)}{4}=\frac{-\cos^2(2x)}{2}$$

But considering now $x=2$:
$$\frac{-\cos(4\cdot 2)}{4}\neq\frac{-\cos^2(2\cdot 2)}{2}$$
$$0.036\neq -0.214$$

What's the error that is behind this process ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The primitive is only unique up to an additive constant.
$$\cos 2\alpha=2\cos^2\alpha-1,$$ so with $\alpha=2x$ we get
$$\cos 4x=2\cos^22x-1,$$ and thus
$$-\frac14\cos 4x=-\frac12\cos^22x+\frac14.$$

Comment: you forgot about constants in both sides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac { -\cos  (4x) }{ 4 } +C_{ 1 }=\frac { -\cos ^{ 2 } (2x) }{ 2 } +C_{ 2 }$$

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that an indefinite integral is only determined up to an additive constant!

You have
$$ \cos{4x}=2\cos^2{2x}-1, $$
so both expressions really do differ by a constant. If you evaluate them at both ends of a range (as in evaluating a definite integral), you will find this constant cancels out.

Answer (score 0):

A primitive is defined modulo a constant. And indeed a duplication formula yields
$$\cos 4x =2\cos^2 2x-1.$$

Comment: @Chappers: Great minds think together :o)